# How do I get HTML buttons with images in them to line up with text buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have two buttons side by side, one with an image, one with text.

I can't figure out why they don't line up correctly on the baseline.

[image: Offset buttons]

Here's the code:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  button {
    height: 20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="image-button">Some text
    <img src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/mini/icons/application_firefox.gif">
  </button>
  <button id="text-button">Some text</button>
</body>
```

I'd love a solution to this, but I'd also love to understand the "why" of this behavior, since it is consistent on all browsers.

Also, I've tried "float: left" on the image, but that doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image you are trying to use?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: try aligning them at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **`vertical-align: top`**

```
button {
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: top
  }
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/4/)

Comment: @GeorgeYates if you check carefully, the buttons are lined up correctly, whereas to text with button isn't.  so try this http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/5/ Hope this is a right way.  share your thoughts.

Comment: Agreed, it's was caused by Firefox applying the vertical align to the button element, not the text inside the element. Your commented Fiddle is definitely a viable solution, it just requires extraneous styling markup, which I try to avoid as much as possible for various reasons, such as SEO.

Comment: I went with this one but used text-top. It came closest to what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two things, one the image is bumping up the line height of that text since it's displaying inline. And two, browsers don't support `vertical-align` consistently. Looking at the previous answers, some of them work in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

My best solution - that works in all the browsers I test in - is to redefine how the image is treated and make it a block element, then float it to the right of the text. That way the image does not affect the way the text is aligned. The downside to this is that you then need to define an absolute width for the button to make sure the image isn't wrapped to the line below the text. Here's the CSS for that:

```
button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
img {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXCsa/3/)

---

Another solution is to use a background-image on the button instead of an img tag, but then you'll need to define a padding on the right side of that button to make room for the image. But then you lose the default styling that the browser places on the button, so you're going to have to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Unfortunately, hardcoded width won't work. I thought about background image, but I want to put this on top of a linear gradient.

Answer (score 0):

The text and the image are lining up on the bottom, but being pushed down by the size of the image. Try setting `vertical-align: Text-top`

More details: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using line-height:

```
button {
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
}
```

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/txdMZ/